# How to fetch latest ordered products using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following database tables and eloquent models (*simplified for this example*):

**order_items** *(OrderItem::class)*

**products** *(Product::class)*

Within the **order_items** table, I have a morphMany `orderable_id` column - however an individual product can be ordered multiple times, so if the last records in the database are like this:

| id | orderable_type | orderable_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | App\Product | 245 | 2022-09-01 17:00 |
| 5 | App\Product | 512 | 2022-08-29 12:15 |
| 4 | App\Product | 245 | 2022-08-28 19:30 |
| 3 | App\Product | 411 | 2022-08-28 11:50 |
| 2 | App\Product | 251 | 2022-08-27 10:10 |
| 1 | App\Product | 123 | 2022-08-26 14:20 |

How do you use Eloquent to select the 5 most recently ordered Products? I don't need to return duplicate values (so only need Product ID **245** once, therefore the correct result should be:

```
245
512
411
251
123
```

I am unable to retrieve all order items from the database, as this is 1000's. Currently, I have a popular product, therefore the result I am getting looks like this:

| id. | orderable_type | orderable_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24566 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-09-01 17:00 |
| 24565 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-08-29 12:15 |
| 24564 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-08-28 19:30 |
| 24563 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-08-28 11:50 |
| 24562 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-08-27 10:10 |
| 24561 | App\Product | 510 | 2022-08-26 14:20 |

This isn't giving me the latest unique 5 products ordered.

I am currently using the below query:

```
OrderItem::whereHasMorph('orderable', [Product::class])
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
   ->take(5)
   ->get()
   ->pluck('orderable');
```

`groupBy()` isn't an option as MySQL strict mode is enabled.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` function

```
OrderItem::whereHasMorph('orderable', [Product::class])
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
   ->distinct()
   ->take(5)
   ->get()
   ->pluck('orderable');
```

Comment: That has no impact over the results and I still see duplicate orderable_id values. I believe this is because distinct() tends to work on the primary key? Or at least doesn't work effectively when there are multiple columns returned.